# DSP-Quantizer class in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, signal-processing

I have written a class to quantize values to arbitrary bit depths within a specified amplitude.
It is meant to process one value at a time, and has two ways of quantizing values.

I wrote the class so that i could create objects of it as a property for another class, so that the quantization process can easily be included into other, more complex operations. This class I wrote, however, has some things I am quite sure about whether they were solved optimally.

My Header file, `Quantizer.h`, looks like this:

```
#pragma once
#include <cmath>
class CQuantizer
{
public:
    ~CQuantizer();

    enum qType {
        lin_midrise,
        lin_midtread,
        numberOfTypes
    };

    CQuantizer(CQuantizer::qType type = CQuantizer::lin_midtread,
        int nBits=4, float amplitude = 1.f);

    float processOneSample(float in);
    void setNBits(int bits);
    void setAmplitude(float amplitude);
    void setType(CQuantizer::qType type);


private:
    int m_nBits;

    float m_amplitude;

    CQuantizer::qType m_type;

    float processOneSampleLinMidtread(float in);
    float processOneSampleLinMidrise(float in);

    float (CQuantizer::*processSampleFunc)(float);
};
```

The first thing I am wondering about is the enum I used for the types: is it a good idea to include `numberOfTypes` as last element for later loops through the enum etc.?

Also, I saw somewhere else for a similar class that as some kind of switch, function pointers were used, which I did for the `processOneSample`-method.
In this scenario, is it appropriate to do so?

Also, below I've included my implementation:

```
#include "Quantizer.h"


CQuantizer::~CQuantizer()
{
}

CQuantizer::CQuantizer(CQuantizer::qType type, int nBits, float amplitude)
{
    setType(type);
    setNBits(nBits);
    setAmplitude(amplitude);

}

float CQuantizer::processOneSample(float in)
{
    if (m_amplitude == 0.f) {
        // watch out for zero-amplitude
        return 0.f;
    }else{
        // use function specified by type
    return (this->*processSampleFunc)(in);
    }
}

void CQuantizer::setNBits(int bits)
{
    m_nBits = bits;
}

void CQuantizer::setAmplitude(float amplitude)
{
    m_amplitude = amplitude;
}

void CQuantizer::setType(CQuantizer::qType type)
{
    m_type = type;

    switch (m_type) {
    case CQuantizer::lin_midtread:
        processSampleFunc = &CQuantizer::processOneSampleLinMidtread;
        break;
    case CQuantizer::lin_midrise:
        processSampleFunc = &CQuantizer::processOneSampleLinMidrise;
        break;
    }

}

float CQuantizer::processOneSampleLinMidtread(float in)
{
    // upscaling
    float out = std::roundf( (in / m_amplitude) * powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f));

    // check for upper boundary
    if (out > powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) - 1.f) {
        out = powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) - 1.f;
    }

    // check for lower boundary
    if (out < -powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f)) {
        out = -powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f);
    }
    // downscaling
    return m_amplitude * out / powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f);
}

float CQuantizer::processOneSampleLinMidrise(float in)
{
    // upscaling
    float out = std::round((in / m_amplitude) * powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) + 0.5f) - 0.5f;

    // check for upper boundary
    if (out > powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) - 0.5f) {
        out = powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) - 0.5f;
    }
    // check for lower boundary
    if (out < -powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) + 0.5f) {
        out = -powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f) + 0.5f;
    }
    //downscaling
    return m_amplitude * out / powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f);
}
```

In my processing methods, i feel like there is too much going on: is there a smarter way for me to round these values and ensure they are within a set range?

(The effect I'd like to achieve with this class is that for a given amplitude, there can only be \$2^{\text{nBits}}\$ possible output values within a certain range.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Omit empty destructor

The compiler will automatically generate a destructor that would, in this case be identical to the empty one your wrote.  It's better to simply omit it and let the compiler do its thing.

### Cleanly separate interface and implementation

In all, the files are fairly neatly divided, but I'd make a couple of changes.  First, I'd move the `#include <cmath>` to the `.cpp` file because it's an implementation detail (and as you'll see a bit later, might not be necessary).  Second, I'd remove the `processOneSampleLinMidtread()` and `processOneSampleLinMidrise()` from the `.h` file and make them static free-standing functions in the `.cpp` file.  More on that in a moment, too.

### Avoid comparing floating point numbers for equality

It's generally a good idea to avoid comparing floating point numbers for equality, even if it's only comparing with zero.  See the oft-cited and still excellent [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, by David Goldberg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for a readable technical discussion for why this is so.

### Reconsider the interface

At the moment, there's no way to read back out how many bits are in effect and no way to find out what the digital encoding would have been for a particular input `float`.  I'd suggest a couple of changes to address that.  First, it is probably useful to provide functions for reading back the publically settable parameters.  Second, I'd suggest splitting the current `processOneSample` into two pieces: `int encode(float n)` which would return the binary encoding of the input `n` and `float decode(int x)` which would return the corresponding floating point value for the encoding `x`.

### Reduce repeated calculations where practical

The expression `powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f)` is used very many times within the class, but it only depends on `m_nBits` and not on any other value.  For that reason, it would make more sense to calculate it once and store the result.

### Avoid floating point where practical

It's often faster to do integer mathematics rather than floating point.  For that reason, and because we know that the result of `powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f)` is always going to be an integer, I'd suggest instead to calculate using the expression `1 << (bits - 1)`.

### Use standard library features

Instead of the current code checking for upper and lower boundaries, it's much more succinctly expressed using [`std::clamp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/clamp) if you are using a C++17 compiler.  If not, it's not hard to write your own version.

### Use `const` where practical

The `processOneSample()` routine does not (and should not!) alter the underlying object, so it should be declared `const`.

```
float processOneSample(float in) const;
```

### Think about future uses

Many people agree that the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principle is a sound one, and I agree with that.  But there is a balance between only coding what's needed right now and anticipating at least the *possibility* that there may be future uses.  An example in this case is using other kinds of digitizing algorithms such as [A-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) or [\$\mu\$-law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm) for audio digitizing.  An alternative approach might be to have a base class (possibly virtual) and then derived classes that implement each kind of alternative encoding.

### Think about whether you need a class at all

This may seem heretical for C++, but not everything needs to be an object.  Really what this code is about is turning one floating point value into another.  It may be that freestanding functions (with the appropriate parameters) might work as well.  It depends on how often you anticipate changing the parameters of the base object vs. how many times `processOneSample` is used.

### Consider using a modern constructor style

An alternative to this constructor:

```
CQuantizer::CQuantizer(CQuantizer::qType type, int nBits, float amplitude)
{
    setType(type);
    setNBits(nBits);
    setAmplitude(amplitude);
}
```

might be this:

```
CQuantizer::CQuantizer(CQuantizer::qType type, int nBits, float amplitude) :
    m_nBits{nBits},
    m_amplitude{amplitude},
    m_type{type}
{}
```

Comment: What is the difference from the constructor style you suggest to the one I used?

Comment: This includes a few answers to that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list

Answer (score 2):

- `powf(2.f, m_nBits - 1.f)` should be a class member, to be computed in `setNBits`.
- Test for `m_amplitude == 0.f` also feels as belonging to `setAmplitude`. This of course requires raising an exception (since it is used in a constructor).

  As a side note, I strongly advise against comparing floats for equality. A very small, yet non-zero, amplitude may yield unpleasant results.
- Clipping is better expressed with `std::min` and `std::max`.